# Firestore REST API runQuery; how to use "createTime" in "orderBy" and/or "where"?

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to find out how to use "createTime" in "orderBy" and/or "where" for a "structuredQuery"

```
{
 "structuredQuery": 
  {
    "limit": 10,
    "from": 
    [
      {
        "collectionId": "posts"
      }
    ],
    "orderBy": 
    [
      {
        "field": 
        {
          "fieldPath": "createTime"
        },
        "direction": "DESCENDING"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Internally I found firestore have convention `__*__` for field that not allow us to use. But I know only `__name__` field available for ordering. I am asking support and waiting for response that are there `__create__` and/or `__update__` available

Comment: Thanks for the info. I asked about it here too:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/3KXPbV1HGuU

Comment: Got answer today and they said it not possible yet while it might really have planned internally and they said many people have request this feature already. Disappointed somehow